# can't use form variables in the controller to save the select data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
<tr>
    <th><%=f.label(:id, "Choose car")%></th>
    <td><%= f.select(:id, @cars_all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><%=f.label(":list_id", "Choose List")%></th>
    <td><%= f.select(:list_id, @lists.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}) %></td>
  </tr>
```

i want to get the value of these two select values to use them in the contorller to add them in the database in a joint table,

```
@car_id = params[:id]
```

doesn't work and doesn't get the data, and is there is away to echo these values

Comment: How does your server log look? What params are sent to your controller?

Answer (score 0):

User can't able to directly access the parameter in controller it will be consist in any of the hash which will same name of form_for object_name
Suppose:

```
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

So the parameter would be in the controller

```
"profile"=>{
"first_name"=>"Daniel",
"last_name"=>"Clark"
  }
```

I would be accessible like in

params[:profile][:first_name]

So In your case please check the form_for object and access it through it.

You can access it through

params[form_for_object_hash_name][:id]

or try to put debugger on controller and check the correct params